# Preventing apps from being uninstalled on Jailbroken IOS

Tags: ios, jailbreak, permission

I would like to password-protect apps *individually* (prevent uninstall) with a long password. On stock IOS this is not possible. Are there any apps that do this on jailbroken IOS 11?

Comment: Password protect apps or prevent them being uninstalled? Your title and body seem like two different questions?

Comment: @grgarside I'm guessing from being uninstalled. Doesn't seem bad enough to be close worthy.